# How can i export all events from Icalendar to CSV

Tags: export, icalendar

One of my clients has allowed me to view their events on ical via icloud.com (I do not have access to a MAC)

What i need to do is export all the events into either a XML or CSV file.

Currently i cannot see anyway to do this. Can anyone suggest a way to get the data out of ical and into either of the above filetypes.

Many Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

**xCal** is a format that encodes iCalendar objects in XML.  You can read more about the xCal in [RFC 6321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6321)